# How to make text and image change in JavaScript within a Slider?

Tags: javascript, image, slider, carousel

I've have this code here: https://codepen.io/double_milkshake/pen/VwZJjgq

```
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const container = document.querySelector('.images');

const textElement = document.querySelector(".text");


let counter = 0;

nextBtn.addEventListener('click',nextSlide);
prevBtn.addEventListener('click',prevSlide);

function nextSlide() {



    container.animate([{opacity: '0.1'},{opacity: '1.0'}],{duration:500, fill: 'forwards'});

    if(counter === 4) {
        counter = -1;
    }

    counter++;

    container.style.backgroundImage = `url(img/bcg-${counter}.png)`


}


function prevSlide() {

    container.animate([{opacity: '0.1'},{opacity: '1.0'}],{duration:1000, fill: 'forwards'});

    if(counter === 0) {
        counter = 5;
    }

    counter--;

    container.style.backgroundImage = `url(img/bcg-${counter}.png)`

}
```

It is a simple image slider. You can't see the images, because the code is made for images that are on your local drive. Every time you click the button, the counter changes and this way the image changes.

Now I would like to change the text, when clicking as well. But not sure How to start this, maybe you guys have any ideas?

Also any suggestions, what to do when I don't know How many images are in my folder. Currently they are hard coded to 5.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what have you tried ?
you could use innerText property to set the value in the text field

Comment: Yes I have tried to do that, but my problem with innerHTML is, when I include it in the function, it only changes the text of the next image. But I would like a every image with another title.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="text" id="caption">
  This is image 1
</div>
```

Javascript

```
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const container = document.querySelector('.images');

const textElement = document.querySelector(".text");


let counter = 0;

nextBtn.addEventListener('click',nextSlide);
prevBtn.addEventListener('click',prevSlide);

function nextSlide() { 

    container.animate([{opacity: '0.1'},{opacity: '1.0'}],{duration:500, fill: 'forwards'}); 

    if(counter==4)
        counter=-1;
    counter = setText(counter, "up");

    container.style.backgroundImage = `url(img/bcg-${counter}.png)`
}


function prevSlide() {

    container.animate([{opacity: '0.1'},{opacity: '1.0'}],{duration:1000, fill: 'forwards'});

    if(counter==-0)
        counter=5;
    counter = setText(counter, "down"); 

    container.style.backgroundImage = `url(img/bcg-${counter}.png)`
}

function setText(cntr, direction){

    if(direction=="up") {
        cntr++;     
    } else {
        cntr--;     
    }
    if(cntr==0){
        document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = "This is image 1";
    } else if(cntr==1){
        document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = "This is image 2";
    } else if(cntr==2){
        document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = "This is image 3";
    } else if(cntr==3){
        document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = "This is image 4";
    } else if(cntr==4){
        document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = "This is image 5";
    } 

    return cntr;
}
```